# “Unable to load popup” when trying to flag posts

Tags: support, flags, popups, flag-dialog

I seem not to be able to flag anything on this computer. Whenever I click *flag*, I receive the little orange box saying “Unable to load popup - please try again (click on this box to dismiss)”.

I use Firefox with NoScript (with exceptions for SO, of course), but I tried to deactivate NoScript, no change. Firefox error console shows no error. I have even tried IE with the same result (which puzzles me the most). I was able to flag at home (on a different computer).

Comment: Versions of IE and Firefox? And have you tried with Chrome? And is this a new problem for you?

Comment: @Benjol - Firefox 3.6.15, IE 8 (x64, if that’s important…); it is not new, I am not sure whether I was ever able to flag anything on this computer or not; I remember the box has appeared before, I just thought it was a temporary glitch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have resolved the problem: By debugging the JavaScript, I noticed there is a failed AJAX request for something like “/posts/popup/flag/123456?=987654”. I tried to access the page directly with the browser and received an empty page. So I tried using wget and received “HTTP/1.0 404 Dropped by firewall”.

So, obviously, our brain-damaged firewall is to blame here (I guess the “popup” part of the URL matched some ill-advised rule), no fault on SO side.

Comment: I have the same problem, for the same reason.

Comment: thanks for the update, hopefully this will help others!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing nothing about javascript but nevertheless trying to debug it with Chrome I seem to find that in my case the culprit is Privoxy.

Comment: Confirmed. I see "Crunch: Blocked" in my privoxy log. Seems to block it because it has "popup" in the path.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93931/how-to-avoid-that-flag-post-shows-unable-to-load-popup-please-try-again-with