# How to avoid that flag post shows “Unable to load popup - please try again” with privoxy enabled?

Tags: support, firewall

Privoxy is blocking my request when I try to flag a post on Stack Exchange sites. Does anyone know how to set it up to avoid that?

Similar to “Unable to load popup” when trying to flag posts, but the solution is over my head.

Comment: Please add that as an answer, and accept it -- hopefully it will be useful for someone else in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. 
In %ProgramFiles%\Privoxy folder edit the user.action file:

Under the Aliases definitions add:

```
{ -block }
serverfault.com
stackoverflow.com
superuser.com
*.stackexchange.com
meta.stackoverflow.com
```